# Loop invariant mistake

Tags: loops

This is from an old midterm. I am looking over it trying to study for my final.

```
Fun(int n, int A[]){
    for(i = 0;i < A.length; i += 2){
        A[i] = n;
    }
    return;
}
```

It asks for the loop invariant, at the location just after the loop begins, before the assignment of A[i]. It also asks what the invariant and exit conditions imply about what the loop achieves when it exits.

I answered:

> Loop invariant is i < A.length
>
> Exit conditions are i >= A.length
>
> This with i+=2 implies that the array A has entries equal to n on every even number n entry less than or equal to A.length

I was not awarded full credit, and think it may be due to the loop invariant. Can anyone clarify?

Comment: It's a small nit to pick, but A will never have an element whose index is "equal to A.length". The last array index is `A.length-1`.

Comment: I think you have to say that *i is the loop invariant* and not the condition as you stated.